# Incrementing alphabet from a specific input

Tags: javascript, typescript, increment

I am new to JavaScript. Here is my task

I want to generate a Serial number starting with 'A' and with numbers in increment manner.
Example : A000001, A000002,...,A000010  and so on.
I want to generate this serial number according to the current year I am giving as an input.
Example :
If current year is 2020, then A000001, A000002,...,A000010  and so on
If current year is 2021, then B000001, B000002,...,B000010  and so on
If current year is 2046, then it should be like AA000001, AA000002,...,AA000010  and so on . Because 26 letters, it should start from AA. Same way for 2047 - AB, 2048 - AC and so on.

```
function colName(n) {
    var ordA = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
    var ordZ = 'Z'.charCodeAt(0);
    var len = ordZ - ordA + 1;
    var year = 2020;

    var s = "";
    while(n >= 0) {
        s = String.fromCharCode(n % len + ordA) + s;
        n = Math.floor(n / len) - 1;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Here I have a code that will generate alphabets in the manner of A,B,C,....Z,AA. But when I call the function colName(n), the value of 'n' should be given from 0 to start from 'A'. I want to give the value as my current year. If I give n value 2020, then it should show 'A'.

I am stuck here and not getting idea about how to do this and how to add incrementing number with this. [Here I am giving an image of my concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX3qe.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subtract n by 2020, to make it starting point (think of it as offset).
Also 2027 will be H not AA, since 2020=A, and 26 characters from there will be Z.

```js
function colName(n) {
    var ordA = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
    var ordZ = 'Z'.charCodeAt(0);
    var len = ordZ - ordA + 1;
  n -= 2020;

    var s = "";
    while(n >= 0) {
        s = String.fromCharCode(n % len + ordA) + s;
        n = Math.floor(n / len) - 1;
    }
    return s;
}
document.write(colName(2020));
```